# Receive windows message inside DLL load in some process

Tags: c++, dll, ipc, windows-messages

I have one application that send custom windows message and i am trying to receive this custom windows message inside a Dll which is loaded into some other process.

Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Give the DLL its own HWND that you can send your messages to. The DLL can either rely on the loading app's own message loop, or it can create its own message loop in a worker thread.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau , I don't know how you assign a handle to a Dll.
Could you please throw some light on that.

Comment: The DLL can call `CreateWindow/Ex()` to create a window for itself, and then run a message loop to service that window as needed.